# gson parsing nested json objects from google matrix api

Tags: java, json, gson

I want to do something like this posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15452172/gson-parsing-nested-json-objects?answertab=votes#tab-top), but using this JSON response:

```
{
  "status": "OK",
  "origin_addresses": [ "Vancouver, BC, Canada", "Seattle, État de Washington, États-Unis" ],
  "destination_addresses": [ "San Francisco, Californie, États-Unis", "Victoria, BC, Canada" ],
  "rows": [ {
    "elements": [ {
      "status": "OK",
      "duration": {
        "value": 340110,
        "text": "3 jours 22 heures"
      },
      "distance": {
        "value": 1734542,
        "text": "1 735 km"
      }
    }, {
      "status": "OK",
      "duration": {
        "value": 24487,
        "text": "6 heures 48 minutes"
      },
      "distance": {
        "value": 129324,
        "text": "129 km"
      }
    } ]
  }, {
    "elements": [ {
      "status": "OK",
      "duration": {
        "value": 288834,
        "text": "3 jours 8 heures"
      },
      "distance": {
        "value": 1489604,
        "text": "1 490 km"
      }
    }, {
      "status": "OK",
      "duration": {
        "value": 14388,
        "text": "4 heures 0 minutes"
      },
      "distance": {
        "value": 135822,
        "text": "136 km"
      }
    } ]
  } ]
}
```

my classes are:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader;

class Response {
    private String status;
    private String[] destination_addresses;
    private String[] origin_addresses;
    private Elements[] rows;

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String[] getDestination_addresses() {
        return destination_addresses;
    }

    public void setDestination_addresses(String[] destination_addresses) {
        this.destination_addresses = destination_addresses;
    }

    public String[] getOrigin_addresses() {
        return origin_addresses;
    }

    public void setOrigin_addresses(String[] origin_addresses) {
        this.origin_addresses = origin_addresses;
    }

    public Elements[] getRows() {
        return rows;
    }

    public void setRows(Elements[] rows) {
        this.rows = rows;
    }
}

class Distance {
    private String text;
    private String value;

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}

class Duration {
    private String text;
    private String value;

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}

class Elements {
    Duration duration[];
    Distance distance[];
    String status;
}

public class JSON {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new BufferedReader(new FileReader(
                "json.json")));
        reader.setLenient(true);
        Response r = (new Gson().fromJson(reader, Response.class));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (String s : r.getDestination_addresses()) {
            sb.append(s);
        }
        System.out.println("getDestination_addresses: " + sb.toString());
        StringBuilder sb1 = new StringBuilder();
        for (String s : r.getOrigin_addresses()) {
            sb1.append(s);
        }
        System.out.println("getOrigin_addresses: " + sb1.toString());
        System.out.println("getStatus(): " + r.getStatus());
        System.out.println("Rows length " + r.getRows().length);
        System.out.println(r.getRows()[0].status);   // here i get null
    }
}
```

But it does not work fully, I can get only this fields correctly:

```
private String status;
private String[] destination_addresses;
private String[] origin_addresses;
```

the are information is null.

Comment: Did you try my solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your declarations are wrong. Change `Response` into

```
class Response {
    private String status;
    private String[] destination_addresses;
    private String[] origin_addresses;
    private Item[] rows;
    ...
}
```

where `Item` is:

```
 class Item {
    private Element[] elements;
    ...
 }
```

and `Element` is:

```
 class Element{
    Duration duration;
    Distance distance;
    String status;
    ...
 }
```

This should solve. Three more tips for you:

1. We are in full generics era, so avoid Element[] and use List instead (and so on, anycase I kept you "style" in answer)
2. Use something like [this](http://json.parser.online.fr/) to visualize your JSON, it will help you to understand its structure
3. `Duration` and `Distance` have the same structure, maybe you can save a declaration, Gson does not care about name of classes, it looks at structure of it. From Gson point of view, Duration and Distance are the same: a string plus an integer.